# WeatherKit can't be accessed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, weatherkit

Whenever I try accessing the WeatherKit, I always receive this message

> 2022-11-03 21:02:37.690374-0500 Weather[151:578] [AuthService] Failed to get remote object proxy for: com.apple.weatherkit.authservice with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=407 "connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice}
> 2022-11-03 21:02:37.6914-000 Weather[151:580] [WeatherService] Encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; location=<+37.785800,-122.441700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/3/22, 9:02:25 PM Central Daylight Time,  error=xpcConnectionFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice})
> erorr
> 2022-11-03 21:02:37.691307-0500 Weather[15211:580478] [WeatherService] Encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; location=<+37.7800,-122.401700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/3/22, 9:02:25 PM Central Daylight Time,  error=xpcConnectionFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice})
> erorr
> 2022-11-03 21:02:38.15636-0500 Weather[1511:5478] [AuthService] Failed to get remote object proxy for: com.apple.weatherkit.authservice with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=409 "connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice}
> 2022-11-03 21:02:38.1562-0500 Weather[15211:588] [WeatherService] Encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; location=<+37.783400,-122.4000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/3/22, 9:02:38 PM Central Daylight Time,  error=xpcConnectionFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.weatherkit.authservice})

Code:

```
Task {
        do {
            let result = try await service.weather(for: location)
            print(result)
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Is this something relates to Auth? I have also enabled WeatherKit in my app bundle, but still receive this response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add WeatherKit as a capability in Signing & Capabilities for your target.

Comment: Thanks. But there is no WeatherKit in the capabilities list for choice in Xcode 14.3, although I could import WeatherKit in my Swift file. My project is written in Objective C ans the Swift file was inserted in the project. When the project runs, the same error as the one in this post just pops up.